# How to get cookie from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I post a request with HttpClient:

```
handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = null,
            UseProxy = false,
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
            AllowAutoRedirect = allowAutoRedirect
        };
        client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://www.example.com")
        };

var sendTask = client1.SendAsync(request);
```

I can not read the cookie in the cookieContainer it is empty;
how to get the cookie?
I see there is an answer in other question that he can get the cookie with  the handler's cookieContainer but mine is empty.

I am sure there is a cookie responsed, how to do it?

Comment: Try to place a breakpoint & peak into the contents object to find the cookie. Do you see it?                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://www.example.com");
                var sendTaskResult = client1.SendAsync(request).Result;
                var contents = sendTaskResult.Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fount the reason that there is no cookie.

I have to initial a global cookie and global handler and only new it once then use every where then it will work.